# Nested control not copying

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following class.

```
 class dgv
 {
     public class DataGridViewEnter : DataGridView
     {
         // Some Properties and methods here...
     }
```

This class is found in two projects exactly the same code.
In project A ( I have acquired it from the internet) the DataGridViewEnter is visually on form that belongs to project A. If I try to copy it to a form in project B it does not appear in the form.
I am sure this because of the structure of the classes,what is the problem? how can I solve it ?

Comment: normal copy/paste...the other controls are copied normally...

Comment: i right click on the control and paste it in the second project...as i told u ,other controls are copied normally using this method and I used all the times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about nested control. Usually it's about namespace. This kind of problem occurs when 2 classes doesn't have the same namespace. Then when you copy the control from designer of first project and try to paste it in designer of the second project nothing happens.

In fact, it's better to avoid copying files between projects and if your projects have some shared classes, put shared classes in a Class Library project and in those projects, add a reference to the shared class library.

But if you want to continue copying files between solution, you should put the class in the same namespace in both projects.

Comment: yes, I discovered that, but still no chance,...I will try your idea about adding a DLL.

Comment: Thank you! it worked. before ur answer i tried to make them the same namespace but leaving them in two different projects but did not work, but moving the code to a DLL and reference it from the same project did the work!